# Recover from ">" prompt in git bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

How to exit from `>` sign in git bash?
I mean I copy-paste some output in git bash and meet that behaviour. I need to exit from that without closing git terminal.

Comment: You probably left a quote open somewhere - just close it and ress enter (or there's always CTRL+C).

Comment: beside a quote not closed, what command can make that thing  to occur?

Comment: That's the only thing I can think of. See @wubwubb's answer.

Comment: Aside from quotation marks, there are a whole lot of other constructs that require closing and will continue prompting for input until closed, such as `$(`, `$((`, `if`, `while`, `|`, `&&`, `||`, many more.

Answer (score 8):

ctrl+c should do it. You'll get the > sign if you entered a double quote but didn't close it. For instance you can make a multi-line commit comment like this:

```
$ git commit -m "added stuff
> 1. this stuff
> 2. also this stuff"
```

But yea you can just hit ctrl+c if you change your mind and just want to cancel the command.

Comment: Heh, I answered a few seconds earlier, but this is very nice for a first answer, nice enough that I'll delete mine and upvote yours. Welcome to SO. :)